# Pandas melt on multi index columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index, melt

I have a pandas dataframe that look something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({('AA', 'A'): {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'},
               ('AA', 'B'): {0: 'd', 1: 'e', 2: 'f'},
               ('AA', 'C'): {0: 'g', 1: 'h', 2: 'i'},
               ('BB', 'D'): {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3},
               ('BB', 'E'): {0: 4, 1: 5, 2: 6}})


  AA       BB   
   A  B  C  D  E
0  a  d  g  1  4
1  b  e  h  2  5
2  c  f  i  3  6
```

I want to unpivot all columns inside 'BB' and keep all columns inside 'AA' as identifiers. So I should end up with something like this:

```
` AA             BB      
   A  B  C Variable Value
0  a  d  g        D     1
1  b  e  h        D     2
2  c  f  i        D     3
3  a  d  g        E     4
4  b  e  h        E     5
5  c  f  i        E     6`
```

The following code does not work

```
df.melt(id_vars=['AA'], value_vars=['BB'], col_level=0) `
```

This sort of work, but does not feel very pythonic. I also end up with an extra columns and the multi-index is flattened:

```
df.melt(id_vars=[('AA','A'),('AA','B'), ('AA','C')], value_vars=[('BB','D'),('BB','E')])


`  (AA, A) (AA, B) (AA, C) variable_0 variable_1  value
0       a       d       g         BB          D      1
1       b       e       h         BB          D      2
2       c       f       i         BB          D      3
3       a       d       g         BB          E      4
4       b       e       h         BB          E      5
5       c       f       i         BB          E      6`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve something similar to your last command using:

```
out = (df.melt(df[['AA']].columns.tolist())
         .drop(columns='variable_0')
         .rename(columns={'variable_1': 'variable'})
      )
```

Output:

```
  (AA, A) (AA, B) (AA, C) variable  value
0       a       d       g        D      1
1       b       e       h        D      2
2       c       f       i        D      3
3       a       d       g        E      4
4       b       e       h        E      5
5       c       f       i        E      6
```

To restore the MultiIndex:

```
out.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([x if isinstance(x, tuple) else ['BB', x]
                                         for x in out.columns])
```

Output:

```
  AA              B      
   A  B  C variable value
0  a  d  g        D     1
1  b  e  h        D     2
2  c  f  i        D     3
3  a  d  g        E     4
4  b  e  h        E     5
5  c  f  i        E     6
```

Answer (score 1):

Break it down into steps: `melt` the `BB` column and merge back to the orignal dataframe:

```py
temp = df.loc(axis=1)['BB'].melt(ignore_index=False)
temp.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['BB'], temp.columns])
df.drop(columns='BB', level=0).join(temp)
  AA             BB
   A  B  C variable value
0  a  d  g        D     1
0  a  d  g        E     4
1  b  e  h        D     2
1  b  e  h        E     5
2  c  f  i        D     3
2  c  f  i        E     6
```

Comment: I think this is what the OP wanted and should be the accepted answer.